# JQuery / AJAX / PHP live search not working as desired

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have made use of the `AJAX` live search tutorial as seen on https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/ajax-search-box-php-mysql/. This is dependent on `typeahead.min.js` as well as `JQuery` and `Bootstrap`.

The problem is, that it is not always getting the href link (it's buggy), as well as the fact that upon clicking on a result, it fills in the input field with the entire href link, which I do not want. I only want to navigate to that page. I feel like my issue may be `JQuery` / `JS` related. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

I have modified the `PHP` to use the `PEAR` extension for `DB` calls, and extended it to include links in the returned results.

Below is some of the PHP file for processing the search.

```
$key=$_GET['key'];

$search_results_array = array();


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Product_Data` WHERE `Product_Name` LIKE '%{$key}%' OR `Product_Tags` LIKE '%{$key}%' ORDER BY `Product_Sequence` ASC";

$q = $db->query($sql);
if (PEAR::isError($q)) {
showError ($q);
exit;
}

$numRows = $q->numRows();

while ($row = $q->fetchRow()) {

  $product_name = $row['Product_Name'];
  $product_id   = $row['Product_ID'];
  $search_results_array[] = "<a href='/index.php?page=purchase&product_id=$product_id' class='livesearch_link'>$product_name</a>";

}

print json_encode($search_results_array);
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="bs-example">
    <input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

And the `JQuery` (Which is where I suspect the issue may lie):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'typeahead',
    remote: '/manage/process_ajax_search.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit : 10,
});


}); 

$(document).on('click','.tt-suggestion .livesearch_link',function(e){

e.preventDefault();

var href = $(this).attr('href');
window.location.replace(href);

return false;

});
```

Please help me!

Comment: This is not directly related to your question, but it's an important note:  your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Learn how to use parameterised queries and prepared statements to protect your database. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the issue, and some examples in PHP of how to use parameters safely.